# python dataframe : How to transpose distinct column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe with unique combination of level and match,

Input Data:

```
level  match params  value
    0      0      m  value1
    0      1      p  value2
    1      0      m  value3
    1      1      p  value4
```

[image]

want to convert into below format, so that I got values in one line for level and match.

```
m         p
value1    value2
value3    value4
```

Comment: no images, please post data as a code or text.

Comment: put data as `pd.DataFrame(...)` so we could copy data and use it in solutions.

Comment: I don't understand your output. Why do you have values `m` and `p` in column `m`?

Comment: removed image and added text @Naveed

Answer (score 0):

[Pandas - How to make new columns from unique values and group by unique value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60467839/pandas-how-to-make-new-columns-from-unique-values-and-group-by-unique-value)

Found solution :
`df_out = pd.pivot(df1, index='level', columns="params", values="value").reset_index()`